# Have one camera preview on two screen

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to make a photobooth on a raspberry pi. I use the Kivy framework for my GUI with the ScreenManager widget.

I would like to have a "CameraOptionScreen" with a preview of the setting and an other screen "CameraTakeScreen" with also a camera preview.

## Here the Kv script for the two screen:

```
<CameraOptionScreen>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            font_size:'40sp'
            text: "test OPTION"
        Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: 500, 400
            preview_fullscreen: True
    Button:
        text: "OK"
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.1}
        on_press:
            app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='up')
            root.manager.current = 'camera_take'


<CameraTakeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        #here the second preview#

        Button:
            text: "OK"
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.1}
```

I tried to add a new camera widget without giving a thought, and i got this error :

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
Unable to stop the stream: Device or resource busy
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./multiscreen.py", line 64, in <module>
     sm = Builder.load_file('./multiscreen.kv')
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 382, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 566, in _apply_rule
     self.apply(child)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 451, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule, ignored_consts=ignored_consts)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 612, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/thenewby/Documents/Git/Photomaton_connecte/kivi/multiscreen.kv", line 169:
 ...
     167:        Camera:
     168:            id: camera2
 >>  169:            resolution: 500, 400
     170:            preview_fullscreen: True
     171:            play: True
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 605, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 33, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1236)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy/properties.c:5171)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 815, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set (kivy/properties.c:11368)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy/properties.c:5933)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy/properties.c:6614)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:13524)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1131, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:12723)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
     resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py", line 67, in __init__
     super(CameraOpenCV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
     self.init_camera()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py", line 117, in init_camera
     self._resolution = (int(frame.shape[1]), int(frame.shape[0]))
```

As I understand, I can not have two camera widget using the resource (which is understandable).

With this in mind, I need to have only one camera class instantiate in my app. I only see two options:

- one: reuse the same camera widget on the second screen.
- two: dynamically create and kill the camera widget for both screen.

For the *first solution*, I found nothing about sharing or reuse widget in different screen on the Internet.

For the *second solution*, I might find a way to do this, but i don't know if it's a good and viable solution.

Comment: So you want the 'video-feed' on both screens simultaneously?

Comment: I will only have one screen visible. I don't need to stream on both screen at the same time. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: One widget you get working?

Comment: yep, I can make work one camera preview, But i needed to change something in the camera script in kivy's code. Where what i did: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5404

Comment: I haven't looked into it yet, but maybe you could try to 'cut and paste' your widget to another screen? I don't know if that would be manageable, but I think it's less resources?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of find a solution. But there is a small problem.

I created a camera widget at the root of the script and set his parent when I showing mu screens. Here is a part of the python script

```
cam = Camera(resolution=(320, 240), id="camera")

class CameraOptionScreen(Screen):
    def loadCamera(self):
        self.ids.camBoxOption.add_widget(cam)

    def killCamera(self):
        self.ids.camBoxOption.remove_widget(cam)

class CameraTakeScreen(Screen):
    def loadCamera(self):
        self.ids.camBoxTake.add_widget(cam)
    def killCamera(self):
        self.ids.camBoxTake.remove_widget(cam)
```

And I just linked my methods on loading event:

```
<CameraOptionScreen>:
    on_pre_enter: root.loadCamera()
    on_pre_leave: root.killCamera()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                font_size:'40sp'
                text: "test OPTION"
            BoxLayout:
                id: camBoxOption
        Button:
            text: "OK"
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.1}
            on_press:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='up')
                root.manager.current = 'camera_take'

<CameraTakeScreen>:
    on_enter: root.loadCamera()
    on_leave: root.killCamera()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            id: camBoxTake

        Button:
            text: "OK"
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.1}
            on_press:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='up')
                root.manager.current = 'camera_save'
```

I's working, but there is only one thing that bother me. When I do the transition between my two screens, I have to remove my camera widget before the transition, and therefore not showing my camera preview when transitioning.